# C Programming - Writing text file that compiles itself

Tags: c, file, compiler-construction, cc

I'm trying to write a file to disk that gets then recompiled automatically. Unfortunately, sth does not seem to work and I'm getting an error message I don't yet understand (I'm a C Beginner :-). If I compile the produced hello.c manually, it all works?!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

    int main()
    {
        FILE *myFile;
        myFile = fopen("hello.c", "w");
        char * text = 
        "#include <stdio.h>\n"
        "int main()\n{\n"
        "printf(\"Hello World!\\n\");\n"
        "return 0;\n}";
        system("cc hello.c -o hello");
        fwrite(text, 1, strlen(text), myFile);  
        fclose(myFile);
        return 0;
    }
```

This is the error I get:

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You compile the file before writing its contents?  So the file is empty then you compile it, and gcc gives the right error, there's no main function in file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're calling `system` to compile the file *before* you've written the program source code to it. And because, at that point, your `hello.c` is an empty file, the linker is complaining, rightly so, that it doesn't contain a `main` function.

Try changing:

```
system("cc hello.c -o hello");
fwrite(text, 1, strlen(text), myFile);  
fclose(myFile);
```

to:

```
fwrite(text, 1, strlen(text), myFile);  
fclose(myFile);
system("cc hello.c -o hello");
```

Comment: Hey, many thanks, it works now. Also, would I need to add an extra +1 to strlen or is it not necessary?

Comment: @Frank: No, that would put a NULL byte at the end of the file which may bother some compilers. Writing out just the length of the string is fine although I'd (personally) add a `\n` after the final `}`. In other words: `"return 0;\n}\n";`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compile the file before you've written the file?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you write the file and close the file first before you call system to compile the file? I believe this is your problem.